# mongodb pass arguments to collection find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, arguments

I am trying to pass the arguments of a function to the mongodb collection find. Like this:

```
async find() {
  try {
    return await db.collection('users').find.apply(null, arguments);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

It returns

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of null at Collection.find (/localpath/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:282:22)
```

I can run

```
await db.collection('users').find()
```

and the cursors are being returned. So connection and collection are properly set up.

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first argument to apply is null, it can not be.

I suggest you pass the reference as the first argument to `apply`, or unwrap the arguments instead:

```
await db.collection('users').find(...arguments)
```

---

clarify what effect null as first argument to `apply` matters...

```
// will log "hello"
({foo:function(){console.log(this.bar)}, bar:'hello'}).foo()

// will log undefined
({foo:function(){console.log(this.bar)}, bar:'hello'}).foo.apply(null)
```

Comment: Null works. Try this:

`
function b(args) {
  console.log('args', args);
};

function a() {
   b.apply(null, arguments);
}

a('test');`

When I use the rest parameter without setting the first parameter to null, I still get the same error.

Sorry for not being able to format the code. According to "help" the backtick should produce formatted code in the comment, but it doesn't.

Comment: did you try it as I stated? with the unwrapping of the arguments? The only difference you doing here is that you suppress the context by apply with null.

Comment: ofc it works in your example, you not referring to the context. it's not a syntax issue, it depends on the code used. let me update the answer to clerify

Comment: Yes, of course, exactly like you stated. As I wrote (quoting myself): "When I use the rest parameter without setting the first parameter to null, I still get the same error."

I you want, I can take a screenshot.

Comment: So what do you set the first argument as?

Comment: ...arguments was the first and only argument. Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: ok, so the unwrapping didn't work, but with no arguments at all it works? in that case what you pass in `arguments` is the issue and not solvable by the information you have supplied.

Comment: You're propably right. In any case, thanks for your explanations and efforts.

Comment: I just noticed, that I had inserted the wrong line. For whatever stupidity or ignorance of mine I still had the "apply" in the code. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: ah, nice to hear it worked out :) gl hf, and visit us in chat if you like to talk nodejs: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js